# Greedy algorithm - Invite guests to a party

Tags: algorithm, graph, greedy

Giving the problem in the link below,

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966249/greedy-algorithm-implementation)

Is it possible to find an algorithm using graphs with less than O(n^3)?

Comment: Reading, the answer to the question in link, the answer seems to be no. Providing proof would be probably very hard though.